# InDesign: Export all placed files into one folder

Tags: adobe-indesign

I've got an InDesign doc ready for to send over to someone. Along with it I've got an images folder full of placed images that the InDesign file references.

While I was making my document lots of images went into this image file, but now it's gone through several iterations and not all of them are still needed/in use.

To keep things simple when I send over this file I only want to send over the images that are actually used. Is there a simple way to get InDesign to export a copy of all its linked files into a 'master' folder?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is one of the problems that `File > Package` solves.

It will scan for any problems (e.g. missing linked files) then copy the document, all the linked images and fonts into a new folder.

Comment: This works perfectly for what i want it for but i was wandering if this is meant for printing, cant you just submit a print ready pdf to the printer ?

Comment: Also do you know if theres an option to export the indesign file as an indesign markup file (for cross version use)

Comment: @sam: For things that are not a simple single-page document, I usually submit a print-ready PDF AND the full package to a printer. For complicated documents, it may be necessary for your printer to do some pre-press {magic} that requires or would be better performed using the source files.

Comment: @sam I only ever submit press-ready PDFs. I haven't supplied an Indesign package in several years. The reality is you need to ask what the printer wants. Many print providers will accept (and actually prefer) getting PDFX/1-a PDFs.