# How to convert all raw-embedded images to placed files?

Tags: adobe-indesign, images, indesign-scripting, embed

[A slightly related question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/13452/4003) deals with exporting all placed files into a single folder. My problem is unfortunately deeper:

The original author directly pasted screenshots into the InDesign document, so they don't even show up in the `links` panel. I can manually select each image and use `File -> Export` to export it as jpg or png. But what I want are the following things:

- no transcoding, i.e. the raw image data shall be exported in whatever format was pasted (bmp I guess)
- the pasted image shall be replaced by a regular placed object
- I don't want to do this manually for all the hundreds of images

So unless InDesign *does* provide means to achieve this via the UI (which I failed to find) I will probably need a script to do the dirty work for me. Has anyone already done something like this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hooray, as [this answer](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/64548/4003) states:

> With InDesign, generally the reason an image is not displayed in the
>   Links panel is because it has been pasted into InDesign.
>
> The script available at the page below will extract pasted (and
>   embedded) images. See here:
>   http://www.kahrel.plus.com/indesign/unembed_images.html
>
> It was created by [Peter Kahrel](http://www.oreilly.com/pub/au/2758).
>
> And, in case running scripts is unfamiliar, he also explains how to
>   [install and run scripts](http://www.kahrel.plus.com/indesign/script-info.html#download_install).